# Apex validation to prevent user to enter records for last working day by a specific time value

Tags: apex, validation, custom

I have a use case where users are required to enter their timesheet records no later than 10 am the next working day.

For this I have created a Business hours profile called 'Krow Timesheet Users' and attempting to use a trigger that is not working.

[image]

Looking for assistance what is the best way to handle this.  I have tried using a point and click validation but that does not work either.

Krow__Date__c is a Date field that a user selects the when entering their Timesheet split records.

Right now, it allows a user to enter timesheetsplits (Timesheet records) for any day any time.

Expected behavior should be, Timesheet splits entered on May 15, 2023 , the trigger should allow users to enter timesheetsplits for May 12, 2023 no later that 10 AM on May 15, 2023.

Also, any attempt to enter the Timesheet splits for days prior to May 12, should also be prevented

```
trigger Krow_Timesheet_Split_Validation on Krow__Timesheet_Split__c (before insert, before update) {
    
    String businessHoursName = 'Krow Timesheet Users';

    
    TimeZone orgTimezone = UserInfo.getTimeZone();

    for (Krow__Timesheet_Split__c timesheetSplit : Trigger.new) {
        
        if (timesheetSplit.Krow__Date__c != null) {
            
            Integer dayOfWeek = (Integer)timesheetSplit.Krow__Date__c.toStartOfWeek().daysBetween(Date.newInstance(1900, 1, 7));
            dayOfWeek = Math.mod(dayOfWeek, 7);

            if (dayOfWeek >= 1 && dayOfWeek <= 5) {
                BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE Name = :businessHoursName AND TimeZoneSidKey = :orgTimezone.getID()];

                if (bh != null) {
                    Date lastWorkDay = Date.today().toStartOfWeek().addDays(dayOfWeek - 1);

                    if (timesheetSplit.Krow__Date__c >= lastWorkDay) {
                    } else {
                        timesheetSplit.addError('You cannot enter a timesheet for a date prior to ' + lastWorkDay.format());
                    }
                } else {
                    timesheetSplit.addError('The business hours ' + businessHoursName + ' could not be found.');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include your additional detail instead of using comments.

Comment: You could probably do this with validation rules and the `WEEKDAY()` function, so you don't have to deal with Apex and BusinessHours at all.  But if you implement this, what happens if someone fails to enter their timesheet?  How do you get the late timesheet data into the system?

Comment: They submit a regularization ticket separately in external HRMS system.  Timesheet data is synced via APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of issues with the code.  The primary issue is going to be

```
Integer dayOfWeek = (Integer)timesheetSplit.Krow__Date__c.toStartOfWeek().daysBetween(Date.newInstance(1900, 1, 7));
dayOfWeek = Math.mod(dayOfWeek, 7);
```

That is getting the day of the week for the 'start of the week', NOT the day of the week for the field Krow__Date__c. Is that what your expecting it to do? As that date will always be the same for the user running the code.

And this SOQL would be best done outside of the for loop for efficiency.

```
BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE Name = :businessHoursName AND TimeZoneSidKey = :orgTimezone.getID()];
```